# Is there API for iphone app to change it's own device bluetooth name?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

Is this functionality available for app developer?
So far I have only seen how to change it from iTune.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think. `NO` there is no `public API` for this. There may well be some `undocumented private method` or with some `Jail Broken devices` ,But as this is not something you put with your `iOS App` On `App Store`

Answer (score 0):

you can change the device name only from settings.